# Multiple linux kernels and whether to keep or remove older versions

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, pop-os

I'm running POP_OS 22.04 LTS, and I'm new to the Linux Kernel aspects. I want to give a shot to the `low-latency` kernels and while digging, I notice that I already have several versions installed.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

returns:

```
rc  linux-image-6.0.12-76060006-generic     6.0.12-76060006.202212290932~1674139725~22.04~ca93ccf           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 6.0.12 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-6.1.11-76060111-generic     6.1.11-76060111.202302091138~1675975749~22.04~f771a7f           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 6.1.11 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-76060200-generic      6.2.0-76060200.202302191831~1678319661~22.04~4d98339            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                     6.2.0.76060200.202302191831~1678319661~22.04~4d98339            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

- Is it an issue to have multiple kernel installed?
- Is there an issue in removing the old ones and how can I remove the
  old ones? `sudo apt --purge autoremove` does not remove anything.
- And finally, why do I have twice the 6.2.0 kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Side note - part of this should have been a comment but I do not have enough points to comment yet.

1. It is possible to have multiple kernels installed. When you install a new kernel, it does not remove the old one. This is incase things go haywire you can always boot up with the older kernel.
2. I have not tested any methods for removing kernels. I imagine that the /boot partition is mounted read-only so you might have to re-mount it read-write and then remove the old kernels. Just a thought
3. I wonder if Generic is some sort of alias for the latest installed kernel.

Things to think about. Again, some of these should have been in a comment.